# web scraping using python notebook

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, text-mining

I am doing web scraping from e commerce website.
I extracted the content I want,
but while printing the output it only gives the last value.
Below is the code I used.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.flipkart.com/search?p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSamsung&sid=tyy%2F4io&sort=recency_desc&wid=1.productCard.PMU_V2"

page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
page_read=page.read()
page.close()
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_read,"html.parser")
mobiles=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"_1UoZlX"})
mobiles[0].prettify()
for mobile in mobiles:
    brand=mobile.findAll("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"})
    brand_name=brand[0].text
    print (brand_name)
```

Comment: what do you mean by last value ?. I've tried to run and got list of all mobile names using same code

Comment: Adarsh Consider the e commerce website has 10 mobiles In single page. While running the code I am getting Only the name of last mobile name listed in page (last one of 10 mobiles Listed )

Comment: https://imgur.com/leaUp91 ..here I use same above code and I'm getting the whole list

Comment: Wow .. okay i will try again ! Thanks !!